# How to retrieve auth user info in +page.ts

Tags: jwt, sveltekit

Most of my pages support SSR and CSR at the same time, that means almost every router folder contains just load function:

```
export const load: PageLoad = async (obj) => {
    if (await ifAuthenticated()) {
        const someData = fetch(from some third party service)
        return someData;
    } else {
        if (browser) {
            goto('/login');
        } else {
            throw redirect(307, '/login')
        }
    }
};
```

My backend is a separate service...

How can I retrieve the access and refresh tokens from cookies when the load function runs on the server side, given that my pages support both server-side rendering (SSR) and client-side rendering (CSR)?

Using +page.server.ts is an option, but it would force the page to use SSR every time it's accessed, which is not desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Using +page.server.ts is an option, but it would force the page to use SSR every time it's accessed, which is not desired.

No it doesn't. It just means that the code will run solely on the server and the client will just request the data as JSON on client-side navigation.

So just use that.

Comment: Alright, however, in this scenario, I must route each API request via my Node server, which will then forward it to another server. This results in a performance loss, and the only reason for this is the constraint imposed by SvelteKit. Nevertheless, is there an alternative method to circumvent this issue?

Comment: If you choose to use a separate service, there is nothing SvelteKit can do about that and whether SvelteKit has to be in-between depends entirely on how the service works. If the service has a way of making the relevant information accessible to clients, you might be able to use the service directly. But there is too little info here to be more specific.

Comment: Alright, now that you have provided clarification, I have gained a better understanding. Therefore, the matter can be considered closed. Thank you.